# How do I add links to this javascript image rotator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hyperlink

Here is the current, working, javascript image rotator. Believe it was originally created with Dreamweaver. Inherited project.

Trying to figure out how to add links to the below function. There are only 3 images that are being used and each needs an individual link. Thanks in advance!

```
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2]; x.onclick=function(){window.location.href=a[i+3]}; }
}
// Comma separated list of images to rotate 
var imgs = new Array('images/swap1.jpg','images/swap2.jpg','images/swap3.jpg');
imgLinks = new Array('http://example.com','http://scifit.com/proseries/proseries.shtml','http://example.com');
// delay in milliseconds between image swaps 1000 = 1 second 
var delay = 8000;
var counter = 0;

function preloadImgs(){
  for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
    MM_preloadImages(imgs[i]);
  }
}

function randomImages(){
  if(counter == (imgs.length)){
    counter = 0;
  }
  MM_swapImage('rotator', '', imgs[counter++]);
  setTimeout('randomImages()', delay);
}
```

Comment: This is very hard to read, it looks like you've posted minified or obfuscated code. Could you post the original source code in a readable format? It will be much easier for us to help you that way.

Comment: A code dump is unhelpful. Can you isolate the specific issue you are having and describe what you've tried so far?

Comment: I'm trying to add links to each image in the array. I've tried creating an another array, but I'm having difficulty connecting the two if you will.

Comment: By the way, please don't remove that code. It was VERY MUCH needed. The above commenters just aren't familiar with Dreamweaver's code snippets, and that's why they've responded like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:
Please use this code instead. I've re-written my original answer, because there were a few problems with it. Replace the entire Dreamweaver inserted code with this:

```
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
    var d=document;
    if(d.images){
        if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
        var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments;
        for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){
                d.MM_p[j]=new Image;
                d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];
            }
    }
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
    var i,x,a=document.MM_sr;
    for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
    var p,i,x;
    if(!d) d=document;
    if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
        d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document;
        n=n.substring(0,p);
    }
    if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n];
    for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
    for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
    if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n);
    return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
    var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments;
    document.MM_sr=new Array;
    for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3) {
        console.log(a);
        if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){
            document.MM_sr[j++]=x;
            if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src;
            x.src=a[i+2];
            x.onclick=function(){
                window.location.href=a[i];
            };            
        }
    }
}
// Comma separated list of images to rotate 
var imgs = new Array('images/swap1.jpg','images/swap2.jpg','images/swap3.jpg');
imgLinks = new Array('http://scifit.com/proseries/proseries.shtml','http://scifit.com/proseries/proseries.shtml','http://scifit.com/proseries/proseries.shtml');
// delay in milliseconds between image swaps 1000 = 1 second 
var delay = 8000;
var counter = 0;

function preloadImgs(){
    for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
        MM_preloadImages(imgs[i]);
    }
}

function randomImages(){
    if(counter == (imgs.length)){
        counter = -1;
    }
    counter++;
    MM_swapImage('rotator', '', imgs[counter], imgLinks[counter]);
    setTimeout('randomImages()', delay);
}
```

Then, in your BODY tag, you'll likely see something like this:

`<body onload="preloadImgs() ...`

Change that to this:

`<body onload="preloadImgs();randomImages();">`

That will force the first call to `randomImages`, which causes the initial image to be bound by the work done in `MM_swapImage`. The reason you were getting `undefined` URLs is because in this line of my code:

`x.onclick=function(){ ...`

I was calling for `a[i+3]` when I should have just called for `a[i]`.

---

By no means is this a great answer from a semantical standpoint, but it works.

Comment: Thank you! Seems I'm very close. Whenever I try to click the actual links though, I arrive at a page that says "undefined." Screenshot: [link]http://imgur.com/nnKLIaf

Comment: I'm not sure if you got my latest edit to the post. Initially, I had posted an incomplete answer. Are you sure you're using the code exactly as it is posted now?

Comment: Hmm.. still giving me the undefined error. Using code exactly as posted. Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: Aha! This could be because I edited the file offline and the javascript is not loading correctly? Since we inherited this project & did not build it, we are not using git or our normal setup. Very old site build in tables, and apparently with Dreamweaver.

Comment: Try it again, now, using my updates above. My code was bad, and I didn't know why until I actually tested it. Your offline work shouldn't be affecting this issue, but then again I don't fully understand your setup. Anyhow, let me know if the above updates help.

Comment: How would I use this same exact example, but only add a link for the first image? The rest of the images do not need a link. Thanks in advance. By the way, I did try removing the other images, but I believe due to the random image call, that it is causing issues. Just trying to bind a link to the first slide. Thank you!

Comment: Btw @vBuck you've been a HUGE help. Still new to Javascript and jQuery and although I'm learning it quickly on the job... this Dreamweaver code certainly threw me for a whirl!

Comment: You're welcome! The quickest solution would be to keep the code you have, but modify every imgLink element after the first to do this: `javascript:;` What that will do is still trigger the click event on the image, and the browser will attempt to navigate by running an empty javascript line of code. That line, `javascript:;` is a shortcut for doing nothing. If you have any other questions, I'll move this discussion to chat, and we can carry on, there.

Comment: that would be helpful. I'm having issues figuring out how to do that using this code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like you don't have enough reputation to chat. So rewrite your `imgLinks` line like so:
`var imgLinks = new Array('http://scifit.com/proseries/proseries.shtml','javascript:;','javascript:;');` That will link only the first image, and not the rest.

Comment: hopefully I can get my rep up quickly! the only issue now is that obviously: `<body onload="preloadImgs();randomImages();">` is causing random images to load with the link, which I'd like to specify for only the second image. Is there any easy way to get around this?

Comment: Alright, well let's take this chat off of SO. Check my profile for my e-mail and send me the source code of the page in question, if you could. No images or other media, just the HTML source code. I'll look at it and get back to you.

Comment: Don't see your email on your profile. But thank you so much. Anyway you can shoot me an email to the one in my profile? Thanks bud.

Comment: Must not be visible ... richard.buczynski@gmail.com